# Shopify setup with external Services

Tags: shopify

So I am thinking of moving my current eCommerce System to Shopify and I wanted to evaluate, if certain functions are available. I am selling software/digital goods, that do have internal protection utilizing a licensing snippet (verifying a serial code). So regarding the most common use-flows, I wanted to check, if the following two things are configurable and of course how to do that:

**1.) Guest Purchase with external license & serial creation:**

1. User makes a purchase that is confirmed and processed
2. Shopify calls an external service for license & serial creation (with users email as unique id)
3. External service creates user, license and serial & sends back serial code
4. Shopify sends out the purchase confirmation mail with order detail & serial code

**2.) User: change of email**

1. Shopify user will try an email address update
2. Shopify will send the update to external service to update external database

I understand, that parts of this are doable with WebHooks, but I understand hooks to be uni-directional and async - so I could not intercept the sending of a purchase confirmation mail to enrich it's content beforehand (e.g. with a serial). Is that correct?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

It is most definitely possible. All you have to do is installl third party shopify apps. There are many of them and you can definitely find some of them to meet both you're needs.

You can get more info [at the shopify website.](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps)

Comment: Not really helpful. I wouldn't have asked, if I had found an APP for that. None of the APPs is really capable of that, except for SendOwl (but with they weirdest, uncomfy solution - and user data stored on 2 additional systems).